# question about out_msg.Destination in MOESI_CMP_directory response message

Tags: gem5

In `MOESI_CMP_directory-L2cache.sm--`the action of `j_forwardGlobalRequestToLocalOwner`, the `"out_msg.Requestor"` of the request message is filled in the **machineID** of that L2 cache, so it is the correct requestor.

While, to response that message in `"MOESI_CMP_directory-L1cache.sm"--`the action of `"ee_sendDataExclusive"` ,when `in_msg.RequestorMachine == MachineType:L2Cache`, why is the `out_msg.Destination` filled in `"mapAddressToRange"`, instead of `"in_msg.Requestor"`? 
(I think it is the `"out_msg.Requestor"` value of the request message.)

L2 cache:

```
action(j_forwardGlobalRequestToLocalOwner, "j", desc="Forward external request to local owner") {
peek(requestNetwork_in, RequestMsg) {
  enqueue( localRequestNetwork_out, RequestMsg, response_latency ) {
    out_msg.addr := in_msg.addr;
    out_msg.Type := in_msg.Type;
    out_msg.Requestor := machineID;// the machineID of the request L2
    out_msg.RequestorMachine := MachineType:L2Cache;
    out_msg.Destination.add(getLocalOwner(cache_entry, in_msg.addr));
    out_msg.Type := in_msg.Type;
    out_msg.MessageSize := MessageSizeType:Forwarded_Control;
    out_msg.Acks := 0 - 1;
  }
}
```

}
L1 cache：

```
action(ee_sendDataExclusive, "\e", desc="Send data from cache to requestor, don't keep a shared copy") {
peek(requestNetwork_in, RequestMsg) {
  assert(is_valid(cache_entry));
  if (in_msg.RequestorMachine == MachineType:L2Cache) {
    enqueue(responseNetwork_out, ResponseMsg, request_latency) {
      out_msg.addr := address;
      out_msg.Type := CoherenceResponseType:DATA_EXCLUSIVE;
      out_msg.Sender := machineID;
      out_msg.SenderMachine := MachineType:L1Cache;
      out_msg.Destination.add(mapAddressToRange(address, MachineType:L2Cache,
          l2_select_low_bit, l2_select_num_bits, intToID(0)));//why do not filled in "in_msg.Requestor"?                              
      out_msg.DataBlk := cache_entry.DataBlk;
      out_msg.Dirty := cache_entry.Dirty;
      out_msg.Acks := in_msg.Acks;
      out_msg.MessageSize := MessageSizeType:Response_Data;
    }
    DPRINTF(RubySlicc, "Sending exclusive data to L2\n");
  }
  else {
    enqueue(responseNetwork_out, ResponseMsg, request_latency) {
      out_msg.addr := address;
      out_msg.Type := CoherenceResponseType:DATA_EXCLUSIVE;
      out_msg.Sender := machineID;
      out_msg.SenderMachine := MachineType:L1Cache;
      out_msg.Destination.add(in_msg.Requestor);
      out_msg.DataBlk := cache_entry.DataBlk;
      out_msg.Dirty := cache_entry.Dirty;
      out_msg.Acks := in_msg.Acks;
      out_msg.MessageSize := MessageSizeType:ResponseLocal_Data;
    }
    DPRINTF(RubySlicc, "Sending exclusive data to L1\n");
  }
}
```

}